# Get Value in different component Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-components

Hello i have get problem when get value from different component.

The Flow is i have 2 different component, first component is ReceiveBookingManageComponent and the second is DriverTablePickerComponent.

And the problem is in DriverTablePickerComponent, but in ReceiveBookingManageComponent i have a form to receive booking by admin, the problem is in Select Type Request Booking, i have 2 choice booking vehicle or booking with voucher transportation. When i choose vehicle, show 2 table vehicle & driver. The problem is in driver table, i have service that use to get driver by period booking that use to validation the driver was booked in Date that has been used, but i get value in DriverTablePickerComponent.

**This is my code receivebookingManage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../../../../component/notification/notification.service';
import { ReceiveBookingService } from './receive-booking.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DateConverter } from '../../../../@shared/date.converter';
import { BookingVehicleModel } from '../../../../@model/booking-vehicle.model';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../../../@shared/employee.service';
import { AppConfig } from '../../../../@core/app.config';
import { EmployeeMemberService } from '../../../master/component/employee-member/employee-member.service';
import { OperationalVehicleModel } from '../../../../@model/operational-vehicle.model';
import { OperationalVehicleService } from '../../../master/component/operational-vehicle/operational-vehicle.service';
import { VoucherModel } from '../../../../@model/voucher.model';
import { DataTable, DataTableResource } from 'angular5-data-table';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DriverModel } from '../../../../@model/driver.model';
import { DriverTablePickerComponent } from '../../../master/component/driver/driver-table-picker.component';
import { VoucherTablePickerComponent } from '../../../master/component/voucher/voucher-table-picker.component';
import { PdfmakeService } from 'ng-pdf-make';

@Component({
  selector: 'receive-booking-manage',
  templateUrl: 'receive-booking-manage.component.html',
})

export class ReceiveBookingManageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() routeBack: EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
  @Input() bookingvehicle: BookingVehicleModel;

  // Datatable resource
  itemResourceDriver: any;
  itemResourceVoucher: any;
  itemResourceVehicle: any;
  itemsVehicle = [];
  itemsDriver = [];
  itemsVoucher = [];
  itemCountDriver = 0;
  itemCountVoucher = 0;
  itemCountVehicle = 0;
  params = { offset: 0, limit: 100 };
  @ViewChild(DataTable) dataTable: DataTable;

  @ViewChild(DriverTablePickerComponent) driverPicker: DriverTablePickerComponent;
  @ViewChild(VoucherTablePickerComponent) voucherPicker: VoucherTablePickerComponent;

  public title: string;
  private config: any = null;
  public vehicles: OperationalVehicleModel;
  public vehicleGroups: OperationalVehicleModel[] = [];
  public drivers: DriverModel[] = [];
  public employee: EmployeeMemberService;
  public vouchers: VoucherModel;
  public isReadOnly: boolean = true;
  public bookingvehicleForm: FormGroup;
  public tampung: any;
  public tampung2: any;
  public tampung3: any;
  public page: number;
  public employeeid: any;
  public passenger: any;
  public pasenggers: number;
  public showVehicle: boolean = true;
  public isShowDriver: boolean = false;
  public isShowVoucher: boolean = false;
  public showVoucher: boolean = true;
  public loading_btn: boolean = false;
  public totalItem: number = 0;

  public time1 = Date;
  public time2 = Date;

  constructor(
    private notification: NotificationService,
    private app_config: AppConfig,
    private receivebookingService: ReceiveBookingService,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private vehicleService: OperationalVehicleService,
    private employeeMemberService: EmployeeMemberService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dateconverter: DateConverter,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private pdfmake: PdfmakeService
  ) {
    this.config = this.app_config.get();
    this.passenger = this.config.Passenger.Passengers;
    this.pasenggers = this.passenger[0];
  }

  // Initialize for Add or Edit
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.bookingvehicle.id === 0) {
      this.title = 'Add Booking Vehicle';
      this.isReadOnly = false;
    }
    else {
      this.title = 'Edit Booking Vehicle';
    }
    this.getData();
    this.buildForm();
  }

  // Set form error
  public formErrors = {
    'employee': '',
    'name': '',
    'functionName': '',
    'startPeriodeBooking': '',
    'endPeriodeBooking': '',
    'destination': '',
    'passenger': '',
    'reason': '',
    'driveMode': '',
    'startHoursOfDeparture': '',
    'endHoursOfDeparture': '',
  };

  // Validation Function to show error messaggess
  public validationMessages = {
    'employee': {
      'required': 'EmployeeNumber is required.',
    },
    'name': {
      'required': 'Name is required'
    },
    'functionName': {
      'required': 'Function is required.',
    },

    'startPeriodeBooking': {
      'required': 'Start Date is required.',
    },
    'endPeriodeBooking': {
      'required': 'End Date is required.',
    },

    'destination': {
      'required': 'Destination is required.',
    },

    'passenger': {
      'required': 'Passenger is required.',
    },

    'reason': {
      'required': 'Reason is required.',
    },

    'driveMode': {
      'required': 'Service is required.',
    },

    'startHoursOfDeparture': {
      'required': 'Start Time is required.',
    },

    'endHoursOfDeparture': {
      'required': 'End Time is required.',
    },
  };

  // Set variable form
  private buildForm(): void {
    let bookingDate: any;
    let startPeriodeBooking: any = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking));
    let endPeriodeBooking: any = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking));
    this.time1 = this.dateconverter.TimeToTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture));
    this.time2 = this.dateconverter.TimeToTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture));

    if (this.bookingvehicle.bookingDate != null) {
      bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.bookingDate));
    }
    else {
      bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date());
    }

    this.bookingvehicleForm = this.fb.group({
      'id': [this.bookingvehicle.id],
      'employee': [this.bookingvehicle.employeeNumber, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(55)])],
      'name': [this.bookingvehicle.employeeName, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'functionName': [this.bookingvehicle.employeeFunction, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      'bookingDate': [bookingDate, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'startPeriodeBooking': [startPeriodeBooking, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'endPeriodeBooking': [endPeriodeBooking, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'destination': [this.bookingvehicle.destination, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'passenger': [this.bookingvehicle.passenger],
      'reason': [this.bookingvehicle.reason, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      'driveMode': [this.bookingvehicle.driveMode, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'startHoursOfDeparture': [this.time1],
      'endHoursOfDeparture': [this.time2],
      'typeRequest': [this.bookingvehicle.typeRequest]
    });
  };

  // Create & Save Function
  public onSave(): void {
    const bookingvehicle = new BookingVehicleModel();
    let driver = new DriverModel();
    let vouchers = new VoucherModel();
    let operationalvehicles = new OperationalVehicleModel();

    if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value == 1) {

      if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value == 0) {
        operationalvehicles = this.dataTable.selectedRow.item;
        driver = this.driverPicker.dataTable.selectedRow.item;
        vouchers.code = "a";

        bookingvehicle.id = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['id'].value;
        bookingvehicle.employee = this.tampung;
        bookingvehicle.passenger = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['passenger'].value;
        bookingvehicle.driveMode = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value;
        bookingvehicle.bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['bookingDate'].value);
        bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['startPeriodeBooking'].value);
        bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['endPeriodeBooking'].value);
        bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture;
        bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture;
        bookingvehicle.destination = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['destination'].value;
        bookingvehicle.reason = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['reason'].value;
        bookingvehicle.typeRequest = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value;
        bookingvehicle.vehicle = operationalvehicles;
        bookingvehicle.driver = driver;
        bookingvehicle.isActive = this.bookingvehicle.isActive;
        bookingvehicle.voucher = null;
        bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderAdmin = 2;
        bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee = this.bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee;
      }

      else if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value == 1) {
        operationalvehicles = this.dataTable.selectedRow.item;
        vouchers.code = "a";

        bookingvehicle.id = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['id'].value;
        bookingvehicle.employee = this.tampung;
        bookingvehicle.passenger = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['passenger'].value;
        bookingvehicle.driveMode = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value;
        bookingvehicle.bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['bookingDate'].value);
        bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['startPeriodeBooking'].value);
        bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['endPeriodeBooking'].value);
        bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture;
        bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture;
        bookingvehicle.destination = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['destination'].value;
        bookingvehicle.reason = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['reason'].value;
        bookingvehicle.typeRequest = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value;
        bookingvehicle.vehicle = operationalvehicles;
        bookingvehicle.driver = null;
        bookingvehicle.voucher = null;
        bookingvehicle.isActive = this.bookingvehicle.isActive;
        bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderAdmin = 2;
        bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee = this.bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee;
      }

    }

    else if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value == 2) {

      vouchers = this.voucherPicker.dataTable.selectedRow.item;
      vouchers.status = 1;
      operationalvehicles.chassisNumber = "a";
      operationalvehicles.machineNumber = "a";
      operationalvehicles.type = "a";
      operationalvehicles.color = "a";
      operationalvehicles.bpkbNumber = "a";
      operationalvehicles.licenseNumber = "a";
      operationalvehicles.chassisNumber = "a";
      operationalvehicles.brand.name = "a";

      bookingvehicle.id = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['id'].value;
      bookingvehicle.employee = this.tampung;
      bookingvehicle.passenger = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['passenger'].value;
      bookingvehicle.driveMode = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value;
      bookingvehicle.bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['bookingDate'].value);
      bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['startPeriodeBooking'].value);
      bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking = this.dateconverter.DTPToDateString(this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['endPeriodeBooking'].value);
      bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture;
      bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture = this.bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture;
      bookingvehicle.destination = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['destination'].value;
      bookingvehicle.reason = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['reason'].value;
      bookingvehicle.typeRequest = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value;
      bookingvehicle.driver = null;
      bookingvehicle.vehicle = null;
      bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderAdmin = 2;
      bookingvehicle.isActive = this.bookingvehicle.isActive;
      bookingvehicle.voucher = vouchers;
      bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee = this.bookingvehicle.approvalByLeaderEmployee;
    }

    this.receivebookingService.saveBooking(bookingvehicle)
      .subscribe(
        success => {
          this.loading_btn = true;
          this.goBack(true);
          this.notification.success('Success', 'Booking Success');
        },
        error => {
          this.loading_btn = false;
          this.notification.error('Error', error.status + ":" + error.statusText + ":" + error._body);
        }
      );

    console.log(bookingvehicle);
  }

  public getData() {
    let a = this.bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking;
    let b = this.bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking;

    this.vehicleService.getAllOperationalVehicleAvailable(a, b).subscribe(s => {
      this.getVehicle(s);
    });

  }

  public openPdf() {
    this.pdfmake.open();
  }

  public getVehicle(AllVehicle) {
    let data: Array<any> = [];
    for (let key in AllVehicle.data) {
      data.push({
        id: AllVehicle.data[key].id,
        machineNumber: AllVehicle.data[key].machineNumber,
        chassisNumber: AllVehicle.data[key].chassisNumber,
        licenseNumber: AllVehicle.data[key].licenseNumber,
        bpkbNumber: AllVehicle.data[key].bpkbNumber,
        type: AllVehicle.data[key].type,
        brand: AllVehicle.data[key].brand,
        brandName: AllVehicle.data[key].brand.name,
        color: AllVehicle.data[key].color,
        year: AllVehicle.data[key].year,
        annualTax: this.datePipe.transform(AllVehicle.data[key].annualTax, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
        annual5Tax: this.datePipe.transform(AllVehicle.data[key].annual5Tax, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
        kirValidityPeriod: this.datePipe.transform(AllVehicle.data[key].kirValidityPeriod, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
        isActive: AllVehicle.data[key].isActive,
        isSelected: false
      })
    }

    this.itemResourceVehicle = new DataTableResource(data);
    this.reloadItemsVehicle(this.params);
    this.totalItem = AllVehicle.totalItem;
    this.loading_btn = false;
  }

  public isShows() {
    if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value == 1) {
      if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value == 0) {
        this.showVehicle = false;
        this.isShowDriver = true;
        this.showVoucher = true;
      }
      else if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['driveMode'].value == 1) {
        this.showVehicle = false;
        this.isShowDriver = false;
        this.showVoucher = true;
      }

    }
    else if (this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['typeRequest'].value == 2) {
      this.showVehicle = true;
      this.isShowDriver = false;
      this.showVoucher = false;
    }
  }

  reloadItemsVehicle(params) {
    if (this.itemResourceVehicle !== null && this.itemResourceVehicle !== undefined) {
      this.itemResourceVehicle.count().then(count => this.itemCountVehicle = count);
      this.itemResourceVehicle.query(params).then(items => this.itemsVehicle = items);
    }
  }

  // To return pageSize
  public onChangeRow() {
    this.isShows();
  }

  // To go back previous page
  public goBack(refresh: boolean): void {
    this.routeBack.emit(refresh);
  }
}
```

**This is my Parent HTMl**

```
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="functionName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ 'Function' | translate }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="functionName" placeholder="{{'Function' | translate }}"
                            formControlName="functionName" required maxlength="50" readonly>
                        <small class="form-text" *ngIf="formErrors.functionName">{{ formErrors.function }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="bookingDate" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ 'Date' | translate }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="bookingDate" placeholder="{{ 'Date' | translate }}"
                            ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="bookingDate" required maxlength="20"
                            readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ 'Booking Period' | translate }}</label>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="startPeriodeBooking" formControlName="startPeriodeBooking"
                                id="startPeriodeBooking" placeholder="{{ 'From Booking Date' | translate }}"
                                ngbDatepicker #e="ngbDatepicker" required readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-success calendar" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="endPeriodeBooking" formControlName="endPeriodeBooking"
                                id="endPeriodeBooking" placeholder="{{ 'To Booking Date' | translate }}"
                                ngbDatepicker #c="ngbDatepicker" required readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-success calendar" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 mt-5 mr-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ 'Booking Time' | translate }}</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3 mr-sm-5">
                                <ngb-timepicker id="startHoursOfDeparture" name="startHoursOfDeparture"
                                    formControlName="startHoursOfDeparture" [(ngModel)]="time1" disabled></ngb-timepicker>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mt-3">
                            <span class="input-group mt-5 mr-sm-5">{{'To' | translate}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3 mr-sm-1">
                                <ngb-timepicker id="endHoursOfDeparture" name="endHoursOfDeparture" formControlName="endHoursOfDeparture"
                                    [(ngModel)]="time2"></ngb-timepicker>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="typeRequest" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ 'Type Of Request' | translate }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control" id="typeRequest" formControlName="typeRequest" (change)="onChangeRow()"
                            required>
                            <option value="0" disabled>Select Type Of Request</option>
                            <option value="1">{{'Vehicle' | translate}}</option>
                            <option value="2">{{'Voucher' | translate}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row show-grid" [nbSpinner]="loading" nbSpinnerStatus="active" *ngIf="!showVehicle">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label class="col-form-label">
                                    <b>{{ 'Vehicle' | translate }}</b>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <driver-table-picker [isShow]="isShowDriver"></driver-table-picker>
                <voucher-table-picker [isShow]="showVoucher"></voucher-table-picker>

       </nb-card-body>
```

**This is my drivertablepicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable, DataTableResource } from 'angular5-data-table';
import { DriverService } from '../../../master/component/driver/driver.service';
import { DriverModel } from '../../../../@model/driver.model';
import { BookingVehicleModel } from '../../../../@model/booking-vehicle.model';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'driver-table-picker',
    templateUrl: 'driver-table-picker.component.html',
})

export class DriverTablePickerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() isShow: boolean;
    @Input() bookingForm: FormGroup;
    @Output() bookking: BookingVehicleModel;
    // Datatable resource
    itemResourceDriver: any;
    itemsDriver = [];
    itemCountDriver = 0;
    params = { offset: 0, limit: 0 };
    @ViewChild(DataTable) dataTable: DataTable;

    public drivers: DriverModel[] = [];
    public driver: DriverModel;
    public bookingVehicle: BookingVehicleModel;
    public totalItem: number = 0;
    public loading_btn: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private driverService: DriverService,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }

    public getData() {
        let a = this.bookingVehicle.startPeriodeBooking;
        let b = this.bookingVehicle.endPeriodeBooking;

        this.driverService.getAllDriverAvailable(a, b).subscribe(s => {
            this.getDriver(s);
        });

    }

    public getDriver(AllDriver) {
        this.drivers = AllDriver.data;
        this.dataMap(this.drivers);
        this.itemResourceDriver = new DataTableResource(this.drivers);
        this.reloadItemsDriver(this.params);
        this.totalItem = AllDriver.totalItem;
        this.loading_btn = false;
        console.log(this.drivers);
    }

    private dataMap(drivers: DriverModel[]) {
        drivers.forEach(f => {
            f.employeeName = f.employee.name;
            f.employeeNRP = f.employee.employeeNumber;
            f.employeeLicenseNumber = f.employee.driverLicenseNumber;
            f.employeePhoneNumber = f.employee.phoneNumber;
            f.employeeFunction = f.employee.function.code + ' - ' + f.employee.function.name;
            f.DriverStatus = f.statusDriver;
            if (f.employee.function.name != null && f.employee.function.name != '') {
                f.employeeFunction = f.employee.function.code + ' - ' + f.employee.function.name;
            }
            else if (f.employee.function.name == null || f.employee.function.name == '') {
                f.employeeFunction = f.employee.function.code;
            }
        })
    }

    reloadItemsDriver(params) {
        if (this.itemResourceDriver !== null && this.itemResourceDriver !== undefined) {
            this.itemResourceDriver.count().then(count => this.itemCountDriver = count);
            this.itemResourceDriver.query(params).then(items => this.itemsDriver = items);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my Errors Output**
[image]

**This is my structure component** (red circle is my location component that have problem)

[image]

So How to get value startPeriodBooking from ReceiveBookingManageComponent to implements in DriverTablePickerComponent ?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the property `startPeriodeBooking` from `bookingvehicle` which you have declared that's an Input property, that means, you're supposed to use the component like this `<receive-booking-manage bookingvehicle="someInstanceOfThat">` in your template, that's how you "get the value in different component" it's called parent to child component communication, [check this video for more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM).

If this doesn't work for you, please add your component templates to the question

Comment: That's not what I meant by templates, you need to attach the corresponding html for each component

Comment: You can check again

Comment: You added the html for the child component, great, however it is the Parent component's html we need to tell wether you're passing a valid Input or not

Comment: I remove html child component sir because cannot insert more than 30000 character in stackoverflow, you can check again in my question

Comment: Actually I need to see receivebookingManage parent's because that's the component with the problem.

Sorry this is taking for ever, are you following? The problem here is that receivebookingManage is expecting an input property, the kind of properties you declare when you invoke the component in another's components template, you need to pass a proper BookingVehicleModel to receivebookingManage.component and apparently you are not

Comment: So i must add <receive-booking-manage bookingvehicle="someInstanceOfThat"> in my component receive booking or my html receive booking? sir?

Comment: somewhere in your application you are using already receive-booking-manage and probably forgot to pass a proper bookingvehicle, that's my diagnose, you should try to find where that happen and use a proper reference to bookingvehicle, you don't need to add another one, you need to fix the one that's not working, you can contact me on discord (Gerardo Sabetta#9679) if you still struggling, I can help you tomorrow. Good luck

Comment: ok thank you for your answer sir :), i will understand first.

Comment: Thank you bro i already understand now, actually is very simple after i see the video you give to me :).

Comment: Glad to help you! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your code is that you have no where defined `bookingVehicle` value. You have simply declared the variable.

```
public bookingVehicle: BookingVehicleModel;
```

and then you are assigning it to

```
    let a = this.bookingVehicle.startPeriodeBooking;
    let b = this.bookingVehicle.endPeriodeBooking;
```

so there is no way, you can render it on html because `bookingVehicle` is still undefined.

Now, looking at your code, you have

> receivebookingManage : Parent Component
>
> drivertablepicker : Child Component

so, you can pass the the value as @input as mentioned in  [Gerardo Sabetta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219267/get-value-in-different-component-angular-6#answer-53219356)